# Can I assign a work item to a group in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online)?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have added a team and also a group inside that project and I can add the group inside the project but I cannot assign a work item to that group or team. It keeps showing this error: 
[error picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFc6Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error mentioned, it's not support assign to the group in VSO directly.

However, **for a workaround**. By assigning a work item to a specific area path you basically **assign it to a team**.  If you use the area path for something else today, you can also use another string field in the work item that specifies the team (https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/scale/portfolio-management)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this. Provided link refers to TFS mostly, screenshots also refer TFS. I'm not able to accomplish this in VSTS.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know work items can only be assigned to specific people not groups